# Using auto-layout in a custom view where constraints rely on frame

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I'm writing a custom view that is initialized programmatically. I override `updateConstraints` to add all the constraints required for this view. :

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    [self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];

    [self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];

    // some more constraints, you get the point

    self.bottomSpacingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:-(0.2 * CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
    [self addConstraint:self.bottomSpacingConstraint];

    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

The problem is that `self.bounds` returns the equivalent of `CGRectZero`. I did my research and according to this [objc.io article](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html), that's expected as the frame doesn't get set until `layoutSubviews` is called. It also mentions

> To force the system to update the layout of a view tree immediately, you can call `layoutIfNeeded`/`layoutSubtreeIfNeeded` (on iOS and OS X respectively). This can be helpful if your next steps rely on the views’ frame being up to date.

However, when I add

```
[self setNeedsLayout];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

right before setting `self.bottomSpacingConstraint` in `updateConstraints`, I still get a `CGRectZero` back for the frame. According to the objc.io article (and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846449/751268)), these methods should trigger layout and update the frame.

Can anybody shine some light on how to make this all work? I'm interested in the solution as well as an explanation of what causes which layout-related methods to be called (for example, it appears that changing an existing constraint's constant in `layoutSubviews` causes `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` to be called, which then triggers `updateConstraints` and causes constraints to be added multiple times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can't, or shouldn't, call `layoutIfNeeded` from `updateConstraints`. Updating the constraints is in an earlier part of the layout cycle, so I don't think it will have the effect you are after.

In your case the solution would be to check the the `constant` property of your frame-dependent constraint in layoutSubviews, and if it needs updating, either update it there or call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` (be careful about causing loops).

You've said updating the constraint triggers another call to `updateConstraints` - this is true, and I think you are misusing `updateConstraints` - it is for *updating* constraints based on changes to your view's content. You should only be adding those constraints if they don't already exist.

Comment: This is what Apple says about `updateConstraints`: *implement this method if your view needs to create custom constraints between your subviews.* Now, it doesn't explicitly say that they should be created **in** `updateConstraints`, but that's what it implies, I believe. If not, where would I create these constraints?

Comment: I'm not saying don't create them there. I'm saying only create them if they don't already exist, as that method can be called multiple times.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't want to misuse `updateConstraints` either. If that method is not really where I should be creating the constraints, then I'm totally fine creating them somewhere else. I just have no idea what would be a better place. If `updateConstraints` *is* the right place, I will wrap the creation in an if statement that checks for their non-existence, first.

Comment: Personally I add the constraints when I create the views. I only change constraints in updateConstraints. But I don't know if that's the _right_ way to do it.

Comment: Great, it does work if I add a `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` in `layoutSubviews`. I guess I'm just confused about the naming of some of the methods. I took `updateConstraints` as "update the set of constraints", not "update the set of constraints and the constants of existing constraints if necessary". Thanks a bunch for your help!