# Parent UIView not resizing after constraint.constant on UILabel changed

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, autolayout

**UPDATE**

**Now Solved** The problem was that when I was updating the `bottomConstraint` I was setting the `Constant` to the bottom padding property. Sounds reasonable but of course the `Constant` should have been set to `0 - BottomPadding`. That explains why the bottom of the text was being not visible, it was being constrained beyond its clipping container.

I have a simple UIView custom control called PaddedLabel that wraps (not inherits) a UILabel

The view hierarchy is

PaddedLabel -> UILabel

When the constraints on the UILabel have their constants updated the outer View does not chnage height.  It is as if the outer UIView is seeing only the Height of the Label as the Height it needs rather than the Height of the Label plus constants. This is how it looks

[image]

In UpdateConstraints I add some constraints and if there is a Text value I set the Constant on the Constraint to the value I want for padding else I set the Constant to 0.

```
public override void UpdateConstraints()
{
    base.UpdateConstraints();

    if (this.constraintsApplied == false)
    {
        this.leftConstraint = 
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.NestedLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1.0f, this.LeftPadding);
        this.AddConstraint(this.leftConstraint);

        this.rightConstraint =
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.NestedLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1.0f, 0 - this.RightPadding);
        this.AddConstraint(this.rightConstraint);

        this.topConstraint =
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.NestedLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, this.TopPadding);
        this.AddConstraint(this.topConstraint);

        this.bottomConstraint =
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.NestedLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, 0 - this.BottomPadding);
        this.AddConstraint(this.bottomConstraint);

        this.constraintsApplied = true;
    }

    if (this.Text.HasValue())
    {
        this.topConstraint.Constant = this.TopPadding;
        // The following code was the problem. 
        // It should have been 0 - this.BottomPadding Now corrected
        // this.bottomConstraint.Constant = this.BottomPadding;</del>
        this.bottomConstraint.Constant = 0 - this.BottomPadding;
    }
    else
    {
        this.topConstraint.Constant = 0;
        this.bottomConstraint.Constant = 0;
    }
}
```

When the Text property is set I set the Text property on the inner UILabel and call `SetNeedsUpdateConstraints`

```
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return this.text;
    }

    set
    {
        if (this.text == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.text = value;
        this.nestedLabel.Text = value;
        this.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21280124/1806119      update constraints should be used for adding missing constraints not for modifying their values, try to change the this.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints(); with the actually setting the constants you want to use for your constraints and afterwards call set needs layout and layout if needed

Comment: That is something i tried previously, and it does work IF the text is being assigned during initial load of the View. However if the text is assigned after the View loads, for example as the result of a background  process it is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the PaddedLabel view to expand and fit around the inside UILabel, change the bottom constraint. You want to tie the bottom of PaddedLabel to the bottom of the UILabel, so as the UILabel grows it makes PaddedLabel expand! The way it is now, you're telling the UILabel to squish itself inside of the PaddedLabel view.

Reverse the bottomConstraint and you should be set.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that now. However the current constraints work fine when the Text is NOT loaded in the background...

Comment: OK I have fixed it. Utter stupidity on my part. Question updated