# Programmatically retrieve the width and height of a UIView using Auto Layout and NSLayoutConstraints?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

How do you get the width and height of a `UIView` who's size and position are set using Auto Layout and Apple's Visual Format Language?

Here's the code (`view` is just the variable from `UIViewController`):

```
// Create and add the view
var stageView = UIView()
stageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) // Since I'm using Auto Layout I turn this off
view.addSubview(stageView)

// Create and add constraints to the containing view
let viewsDictionary = ["stageView":stageView]
let horizontalConstraints: NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-150-[stageView]-150-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
let verticalConstraints: NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-100-[stageView]-150-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)        
println("stageView.frame=\(stageView.frame)")
```

and got:

```
stageView.frame=(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
```

so I tried:

```
let fittingSize = stageView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
println("fittingSize=\(fittingSize)")
```

and got:

```
fittingSize=(0.0,0.0)
```

I can't seem to find a way to get the size.  I'm able to add subviews to `stageView` that place just fine using Auto Layout and Visual Format Language, but I can't get width and height for `stageView` which I need to further position those subviews.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding a `layoutIfNeeded`. Your constraints aren't applied immediately.

Comment: You're right, this worked.  @Aaron's answer has more information, but I think some might like the simplicity of this answer. Feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll up vote both answers as they were both useful to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

You can force the layout engine to size the views immediately by calling `setNeedsLayout` and then call `layoutIfNeeded`. This is *not recommended* because it's inefficient and any manual frames required for layout might not have been set yet. You can read more about this approach on my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20713533/1445366).

You can also wait until the subviews have been updated in the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    println("stageView.frame = \(stageView.frame)")
}
```

If you want to know within a `UIView` subclass (or more often, a `UITableViewCell` subclass, you can check after `layoutSubviews` has run:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    println("self.frame = \(self.frame)")
}
```

Comment: Good insight.  In my case, I need to know the size of the stageView before all of the subviews have been laid out because the size and position of some of the subviews are based on the size of stageView.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TenaciousJay You can probably just express those as constraints between your subviews and their superviews. Then you don't have to worry when layout happens.

Comment: @AaronBrager using `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`, can I specify the width, so that the view will expand vertically, keeping a fixed width?

Comment: @nil you could, but why not just add a fixed width constraint?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the frame inside viewDidLayoutSubviews.
This function run after constraint calculation 
Its suppose to look something like this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    //Print frame here   

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this did not work in my case as I need to know the size of stageView before the rest of the subviews are laid out.

Comment: Did the other answer help you? or you need me to try to think on different solution?